# Maintaining multiple JDBC connections in Struts2

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, struts2, jndi

The number of connections to DB exceeds the permissible limit.

This is what I tried so far.

When the user successfully logs in I add one connection object to the session:

```
Connection conn = DatabaseConnectionManager.getConnection();
sessionMap.put("Connection", conn);
```

then, whenever I need a DB connection, I fetch it from the session:

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = (Map<String, Object>) ActionContext.getContext().get("session");
Connection conn = (Connection) sessionMap.get("Connection");
```

In the `getConnection()` method I print the number of times the method is called.
So although I fetch the Connection object from the session why does the number of connections exceed the permissible limit which is 50 ?

JNDI Code:

```
Connection conn = null;         
try {
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MySqdb");
    conn = ds.getConnection();

}  
catch (NamingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnectionManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
catch (SQLException sqle) {
    sqle.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("connection: "+connection++);
return conn;
```

I have used JNDI. The number of connections is within the permissible limit. I'm not sure if this is the right way, please advise.

Comment: Do you know web-application's life cycle and server/client sided programming??? JDBC connection pool is property of server it should not be traveled over httpSession in my opinion.

Comment: I thiink I do. I was expecting the downvote. I am open to criticism as long as it leads me in the right direction.

Comment: Use some connection pool.

Comment: JBoss AS >= 7 ? Java EE >= 6 ? Are you at the beginning, or can you refactor the code ? If we have 3 yes, then use JPA 2, and forget about connections, DAO layers, queries, and other old fashioned stuff

Comment: Well @wib, I won't write any answer about this since it is too broad and it would not even answer your actual question, but believe me: since you have the 3 yes, go with Java EE 6: JPA2.0 + EJB 3.1 + CDI. And consider using the super-minimalist [ECB Pattern advocated by Adam Bien](http://tinyurl.com/yztxl96). It changed the way I work and increased the quality of my products. [Forget about DAO](http://tinyurl.com/pzh9bjb), connections, and focus on your business only, like it should be. I've also asked [a question](http://tinyurl.com/or8azup) on it, that might be worthy of a read. Good luck ;)

Comment: Did you forget to close a connection after the action is executed?

Comment: well writing the `connection.close` statement was getting cumbersome. So I thought maybe I should allow for one open connection per user. Therefore storing it in the session was the initial idea.

Comment: You are embracing the Dark Side. Never embrace the Dark Side.

Answer (score 2):

One connection for each user is not a good solution at all. As mentioned you must use some connection poll and if you want something simple use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ .
As mentioned there:

> Creating a new connection for each user can be time consuming (often
>   requiring multiple seconds of clock time), in order to perform a
>   database transaction that might take milliseconds. Opening a
>   connection per user can be unfeasible in a publicly-hosted Internet
>   application where the number of simultaneous users can be very large.
>   Accordingly, developers often wish to share a "pool" of open
>   connections between all of the application's current users. The number
>   of users actually performing a request at any given time is usually a
>   very small percentage of the total number of active users, and during
>   request processing is the only time that a database connection is
>   required. The application itself logs into the DBMS, and handles any
>   user account issues internally.

You can find samples at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/

Comment: I have used JNDI. Please have a look

Comment: With JNDI your refer to a resource, if your resource is **JDBC Datasource** yes you are correct. Please read **JDBC Data Sources** section at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html